# Apple planning to release new Mac Pro?

Tags: mac, mac-pro, design

With the Mac Mini getting a new release, what is happening with the Mac Pro (aka the "Trash Can")? It has not had any design changes since 2013, and 5 years later it would seem that Apple would plan to give it a new look. I read some articles that claim how Apple will change the Mac Pro, but are these statements true or can they be backed up by official Apple releases?

A quick search online brings you to either pages that stay on-the-surface of the topic, not going into much detail, or just fan concept drawings. Some places give info that they claim was released by Apple.

What has Apple officially released about there being a new Mac Pro, if they have released anything?

Comment: Recommendation questions about Apple's future plans is generally off topic. Unless you're asking "Has Apple announced a date?" or "Has Apple committed to a specific design publicly?" Which would be a yes/no question - this is asking for recommendations on a prediction - https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question-on-ask-different

Comment: Also - there's no need to down vote a question that's on hold. An edit might make it on topic and not it has down votes that don't reflect the actual question being asked. I've cast an offsetting +1 since I disagree with the -1

Comment: I am not looking for a shopping question , but rather looking for answers on if and when the Mac Pro is getting updated. I asked this without the intent of purchasing via help from shoppers, but with the intent of asking a place where there is knowledge of Apple and their plans with their product line. I re-worded the question, so if there is more that I should change let me know and I will greatly appreciate it. @bmike

Comment: Thanks for the edit - it's really off topic still for this site. Hit us up on [meta] if you're not understanding why I put a close / hold on a question asking about future announcements. I've edited out the "shopping guess" - it's still looks like this revolves around asking about predictions as opposed to what Apple has announced or done.

Comment: All they have released is that one is coming sooner or later, probably 2019, everything else are rumors. Please be aware that nobody here has any insights into Apple‘s plans (and those who do are not allowed to tell), also this site focuses on practical problems with verifiable answers.

Comment: I have changed the answer with the constructive feedback of @bmike thank you for providing helpful feedback and not immediately down-voting it unlike other people in the past who down-voted me, and never responded to help me form better questions.

Answer (score 1):

A new modular Mac Pro will ship sometime in 2019, along with a new Apple display.

https://9to5mac.com/2018/04/06/2019-mac-pro/

Comment: I'm not going to -1 vote you, but that article is crap and rumor and says a dozen times - it might ship in 2018 it might not ship in 2018 "we don't know" - what a load of hype and click bait. My opinion is articles all filled with "Apple can do this" and "Apple can't do this" are rarely worth the time to read. But since this is off topic for the main site - let's meet in some discourse forum or [chat] to talk about rumors if anyone is here for that.

Comment: I just used the article to source the two things I said, but those two statements are coming directly from Apple, so I'm not sure why you're saying it's a rumor. 


Here's the direct quote from Apple: "We want to be transparent and communicate openly with our pro community so we want them to know that the Mac Pro is a 2019 product. It's not something for this year."

Edit: This article also contains a direct quote from Phil Schiller referencing the display: https://daringfireball.net/2017/04/the_mac_pro_lives

Comment: I'm +1 your answer since you are clearly here to show references and answer the question / whether it's on topic or not - I think a DF link or something quoting Apple more directly with less "click bait" would be preferred. Thanks so much for the contributions. Editing your answer to have Apple references or augmenting them would be ideal but not required.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, first question I've ever answered here, I'll be more clear with sources in the future.